# How to update large objects without blocking other read threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, duplicates

I have a large object that will be accessed by multiple threads continuously. But this object has to be updated periodically and while updating no thread shouldn't be blocked.

I think we can have a Timer to update the object that updates in a duplicate object and once the update is done we can update the object reference with the duplicate object.

Does any one has a better ideas to implement this effectively?

Comment: But what if two threads create a duplicate object with updates at the same time? Then you will lose one of the updates.

Comment: "while updating no thread shouldn't be blocked" that confuses me, since you need a thread to update it and the others need to wait while it is updated.

Comment: Would you share some code to illustrate your problem? That would make it easier to share code to illustrate an answer.

Comment: Only one thread will update the object as configured by the timer and for the rest of the time it will be idle.

Comment: What I meant by "while updating no thread shouldn't be blocked" was during the data pull and inserting the data into the object, other threads no need to wait until it finishes. They can run with the older data.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement read/write locks for each property of the object unless you have dependencies between properties.

Comment: You should mention the ReentrantLock class.

Comment: There is only one property(object). The problem with read/write locks is every time you read you have to check whether the lock is free or not. And moreover, I don't want threads that reads this data will be blocked during the write.

Comment: Maybe you can use a "copy on write" style update. That way the old object would be left in a consistent state and would then be replaced by a new object in one go.

Comment: Can you elaborate it how can we do? I am just looking for different possible solutions for the problem. One way is we can make the object as volatile. If you have any other ways, I am happy to listen them.

Comment: See ReadWriteLock in java.util.concurrent.locks. You would basically allow concurrent read access as long as there are no write operations in progress (locking before setting the property - unlocking afterwards). if this is done per property of a large object, you would gain a ConcurrentHashMap like striping effect

Comment: Thanks but we don't want to have the locking overhead.

Comment: The read locks basically cost you close to nothing. If you update a copy and only write lock during the swapping the update and the old entry, you should be very close to zero blocking

Comment: Updates are very minimal so don't think locking would be needed here as it has extra overhead(may be minimum). Other than, locking can we any other way something like maintaining a duplicate copy and update the reference with the new object once the update is done.

Comment: Ok.understood you are also telling the same thing.

Comment: In general locking would only be required if your update are non-atomic. If not you would have a good chance of reading a half-updated state which could lead to interesting data corruption scenarios.